# MYSQL LEFT OUTER JOIN Query not returning all results

Tags: mysql, sql

The query below does not return any values for `name1` because it does not have `wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'wpcf-phone'`. I'm using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` thinking it will return results for `name1` as it has values in `wp_posts` but it's only return values for `name2` which does have a `wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'wpcf-phone'`.

```
SELECT 
  wp_posts.ID,
  wp_posts.post_content,
  wp_posts.post_title,
  wp_postmeta.meta_value AS phone
FROM
  wp_posts
  LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
WHERE
  wp_posts.post_type = 'solicitors' AND 
  wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND 
  wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'wpcf-phone' AND 
  (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%name1%' OR 
  wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%name2%')
```

Comment: why mix and match the on clause with the where clause if you dont have to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing the outer table in your where clause in this line:

```
wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'wpcf-phone'
```

thereby eliminating all rows where `wp_postmeta.meta_key` is null, effectively turning your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` (since `NULL = 'wpcf-phone'` is false).

You should move your condition to the join:

```
SELECT 
  wp_posts.ID,
  wp_posts.post_content,
  wp_posts.post_title,
  wp_postmeta.meta_value AS phone
FROM
  wp_posts
  LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta wp_postmeta 
    ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
    AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'wpcf-phone' 
WHERE
  wp_posts.post_type = 'solicitors' AND 
  wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND 
  (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%name1%' OR 
  wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%name2%')
```

Answer (score 1):

When an `OUTER JOIN` 'fails to connect' it fills the fields in the output with `NULL` values. You can thus use `OR IS NULL` to test for this condition. The WHERE-clause should thus be something like:

```
WHERE
  wp_posts.post_type = 'solicitors' AND 
  wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND 
  (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'wpcf-phone' OR
      wp_postmeta.meta_key IS NULL) AND 
  (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%name1%' OR 
      wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%name2%')
```